# How to express a filter that relies on adjacent elements in a list, functionally

Tags: list, haskell, fold

Several times I've wanted to traverse a list and pick out elements that have some property which also relies on, say, the next element in the list. For a simple example I have some code which counts how many times a function `f` changes sign over a specified interval `[a,b]`. This is fairly obvious in an imperative language like C:

```
for(double x=a; x<=b; x+=(b-a)/n){
    s*f(x)>0 ? : printf("%e %e\n",x, f(x)), s=sgn(f(x));
    }
```

In Haskell my first instinct was to zip the list with its tail and then apply the filter and extract the elements with `fst` or whatever. But that seems clumsy and inefficient, so I shoehorned it into being a fold:

```
signChanges f a b n = tail $       
    foldl (\(x:xs) y -> if (f x*f y)<0 then y:x:xs else x:xs) [a] [a,a+(b-a)/n..b]
```

Either way I feel there is a "right" way to do this (as there so often is in Haskell) and that I don't know (or just haven't realised) what it is. Any help with how to express this in a more idiomatic or elegant way would be greatly appreciated, as would advice on how, in general, to find the "right" way to do things.

Comment: I think you should go with your first instinct.  Your fold solution recomputes `f` for each element twice, so it's not that efficient.

Comment: You can use a paramorphism which is a recursion scheme that lets you travel through a list and peek at the rest of the list at the same time. Unfortunately `para` is not in the Prelude or Data.List, so it is nowadays idiomatic to zip the list against its tail as you recognized. To my taste, I find a paramorphism the more elegant solution.

Comment: @stephentetley that sounds more like it. A bit of preliminary research indicates I'm going to have to learn a lot of the scary haskell words before I can understand enough to write such a function (not that I'm not willing to). Any chance you could provide a snippet/link to an example?

Comment: Did you mean `s*f(x)<0` in your imperative code?

Comment: @AndrewC nope, `cond : ? val` is a gnu extension to C and equivalent to `if cond then cond else val`, so I want to find intstances where the condition is false. Thanks for checking though, 90% of the time I really am wrong.

Comment: Oops, I didn't spot the syntactic sugar ` ` for the noop between the `?` and `:`, so didn't spot the `:` and wrongly assumed the printf was in the middle block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a "version" using a paramorphism (not quite the same as the question - but it should illustrate a paramorphism usefully enough), first we need `para` as it is not in the standard libraries:

```
-- paramorphism (generalizes fold)
para :: (a -> ([a], b) -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
para phi b = step
  where step []     = b
        step (x:xs) = phi x (xs, step xs)
```

Using a paramorphism is much like using a fold but as well as seeing the accumulator we can see the rest of input:

```
countSignChanges :: [Int] -> Int
countSignChanges = para phi 0
  where
    phi x ((y:_),st)  = if signum x /= signum y then st+1 else st
    phi x ([],   st)  = st


demo = countSignChanges [1,2,-3,4,-5,-6]
```

The nice thing about `para` compared to zipping against the tail is that we can peek as far as we want into the rest of input.

Comment: With zipping you can use `drop` instead of `tail` if you want peeking distance other than one. The distance is fixed though - `para` is more flexible as it allows for variable distance and peeking multiple values.

Answer (score 4):

Zipping is efficient if you run with -O2 as list fusion engages. No need to resort to folds in this case is one of essential advantages of Haskell as it improves modularity.

So zipping is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to calculate value for **i-th** element, but depending on **j-th** element of the list, it's better to convert list to [Array](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays), either mutable or immutable.

So you will be able to do arbitrary computation based on index of current element either in fold, or in recursive calls.

Comment: In this instance, only adjacent elements are needed, so array is overkill.